# Tastypie POST always creates resource

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

I am building an API using Tastypie.

I created a resource but for some reason whenever I make a POST request it ALWAYS creates a resource even when it returns with an error.

For example, I get the following error:

> The 'authors' field has no data and doesn't allow a null value

But when I check the resource in the admin console it shows that it created the resource and simply set the 'authors' field as blank.

I need the POST request to fail and not create a resource if a parameter is missing.

By default all the fields in the model are blank=False and null=False.

EDIT

Here is the model I am using:

```
class Story(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='stories')
  cover_photo_url = models.URLField(max_length = 200)
```

Here is my resource:

```
class StoryResource(ModelResource):
  authors = fields.ToManyField(SimpleAuthorResource, 'authors', full=True)
  posts = fields.ToManyField(PostResource, 'posts', full=True, blank=True)
  class Meta:
    queryset = Story.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'story'
    authorization = Authorization()
  def determine_format(self, request):
    return "application/json"
```

I am making the following request:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-type:application/json" 
     --data '{"title" : "cool new story", "cover_photo_url":"hello.png"}' 
     http://localhost:8000/api/v1/story/
```

Now I've been trying some other things. Including validation and thats caused its own set of problems.
Even without validation shouldnt the row insertion have failed if I tried to POST with a missing required parameter?

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried so far?  In particular, could you add a [Short, Self-Contained, (Compilable) Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)? (or at least enough code to see how you are handling post requests, etc) That's the best way to get help on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added some code.

Comment: Could you please provide a traceback? I'm interested in where exactly the exception was raised. The exception that resulted in "The 'authors' field has no data and doesn't allow a null value" that is.

Comment: I'm seeing this same error, and believe it may be a bug in TastyPie.  TastyPie populates M2M data after the resource, even if the M2M is required.  I'll post here if I learn more.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. I was using a m2m in the Resource and a ForeignKey in the model.

Answer (score -1):

By default, all models have blank = False.
You have to specifically add blank = True to your author model in order for the API to ignore a blank author.
The other option is to have a default author which would populate the author field and then you would not have to worry about it not being blank.

Comment: Not an answer to this question - In this case, an Author is required for every Story.